# browser-sync is not auto refreshing

Tags: javascript, browser-sync, livereload

I re-read the guides on the grunt watch page and followed 3 different examples elsewhere but I cannot get it to auto refresh my page when an html or js file is modified... i mean I am getting the "File changed: views/entryw.html" messages though so its being watched but no signs of auto reload / auto refreshing

my server is run on port 9000

This is what my Gruntfile.js looks like:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // Configuration
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    grunt.initConfig({  
        browserSync: {
            bsFiles: {
                src : [
                    'forbiddenDirectory/*.js', 
                    'views/*.html'
                ]
            },
            /*options: {
                server: {
                    baseDir: "./"
                }
            }*/
            options: {
                proxy: "localhost:3000",
                open: false
            }
        }
    });


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // Load plugins
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');



    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // register tasks
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserSync']);

    //grunt.registerTask('all', ['default']) // each index in array is the name of registered tasks above

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`proxy` option](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-proxy) should point to your server on port 9000 like so:

```
options: {
  proxy: 'http://localhost:9000'
}
```

You can then access your application through browser-sync at http://localhost:3000, which will serve the actual server on port 9000 via proxy.

YMMV, as your server might need to be restarted for the changes to take effect.